# Dynamically change itemsource of listview doesnt update the display

Tags: listview, binding

I have a listview with itemsource set to observablecollection'x' with converter that change it to observablecollection'ucx' (with foreach procedure) where "ucx" is a usercontrol, describing "x", that I want to display in the listview.

I made a test in which I set observablecollection'x' and the display worked (so the converter & binding is ok), but when I change observablecollection'x' dynamically the display doesn't changed.

`OnPropertyChanged("x")` is set!

I prefer not to bind to observablecollection'ucx' directly without converter because its not exist and i don't want to add another collection to the class.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I think you should look at:

In ListView you have the option to set the "ItemTemplate" which is a DataTemplate which can hold the ucx user control. something like:

```
  <ListView ItemSource={Binding items}>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ucx/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

(Should see help for more specific examples)

What do you mean changed the observablecollection'x'? add/remove items?
maybe upload a code example of your binding, might help.